# Xmlhttp status check when url is down without libraries like Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to check if the given url is working or not using ajax. So i modified the Ajax a little bit.

```
function isServerAlive()
{
var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
   // code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
   {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.status;
   }
  }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","wrongurl",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

All i want to do is it to display the xmlhttp.status as 404 or 503 when the url is wrong. But it is not printing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have status code available in `.status` and the text in `.statusText`

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
           console.log("Code: " + xmlhttp.status  + "Status text: " + xmlhttp.statusText);
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm i get xmlhttp.status as zero. So is it right if i say return(xmlhttp.status===0) inside this onreadystatechange ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You should actually be comparing with the usual HTTP status codes.

Comment: user1536201: if status is 0 then the HTTP headers have not been recieved. Generally this is caused by a connection error. To catch such events, use .onerror.

Thrustmaster The onRSC event gets passed a response object. I'd suggest using it due to the global object being updated before/while the event is being dispatched and could lead to you accessing what would appear to be invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

a respone object is passed to the xmlhttp events, so use this instead:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(r) {
    if (r.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = r.status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd be able to use XHR to check if url is working, as the url has to be from [the same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) as the original page. First check if your solution works correctly when accessing a local url.